# ElasticSearch - does it make sense to separate rarely used documents for faster performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm designing a system which will have **~2M** documents and **95%** percent of the queries will be targeted against **40-50k** documents.

Documents in the system have two states bool fields `active` and `inactive`.

I have ~50k in the state `active` and the rest 1.95 million are `inactive`.

So my questions is does it make sense to separate these documents? How can I separate them? Do I need to worry about this at all? Maybe I can use shards and a hash function which chooses buckets depending on the state active/inactive?

I can also introduce two indexes, one which holds `active` and one for the `inactive`, that way most of the queries will do a lookup in small database. This solution however will require more maintenance and can cause more headaches in the long run.

I'm not fully aware of the capabilities provided by ES and I would love to hear someone with more experience.

Comment: It depends on your cluster. 2M record for a cluster using 16 GB RAM and SSD hard is so light. I have cluster of 4 servers with 128 total RAM and with SSD hard. I have currently about 5 billion records on it and its performance is totally acceptable